# How to remove blank spaces in line with regex?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have file like below.,

```
 23,1:30 - 2:00,10,,,,

 23,1:30 - 2:00,600,,,,

   23,1:30 - 2:00,600,,,,
23,1:2 - 23:00,321,,,,
```

Now i need to remove the blank spaces in whole file and replace it with empty.

I have already tried with This regex  for search \ s+ and replace with \n it doesn't work

So i have need search and replacement value for find blank spaces and replace it with empty like below output.

```
23,1:30 - 2:00,10,,,,
23,1:30 - 2:00,600,,,,
23,1:30 - 2:00,600,,,,
23,1:2 - 23:00,321,,,,
```

And finally need search and replacement value for ReplaceText processor which perform my requirements.

Comment: Post your attempts..

Comment: @avinash I have posted my attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
regex search >>  \n+\s+
replace with >>  \n
```

see [demo](http://regexr.com/3fc03)

Comment: I will check and let you know siam